# CSS3 display as block

Tags: html, css

Okay, I accidentally make my display for the unordered list, rather for the <li> into block style, like the following:

```
li{
  display: block;
}
```

And I realize, that my bullet was hidden as I input that style, so I don't need to add list-style, as the following:

```
li{
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
}
```

But, the question is : What is the result of displaying as block? Because I think, by default the <li> and most of the HTML tags is displaying as block, so in the first place, I do agree that whether I add "display: block" or not, It doesn't make any sense, except for the new giving tags for HTML5, such as, <nav> <header>, <footer>, etc, which I know for sure it's neccesary for the earlier browser.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the question? You already seem to know the result of displaying the `li` as block

Comment: What is exactly the result for giving display as block? Because, in the first place, I think without inputing the display as block doesn't make any change.

Comment: @Danield Yes, I do realize the result for li tags, but, is there any other properties that will change if I input the display as block for other tags?

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason you might want an `li` to be `display: inline`, you may want an `a` (which is an inline element), to be `display: block`.

Quick example:

```css
a {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">I'm big!</a>
```

Note how the larger area is clickable, you wouldn't be able to set width and height on an inline, so `display: block` (or `display: inline-block`) works nicely for this purpose.